# K&R code example confusion: copy string

Tags: c, arrays, string

In chapter one, the K&R introduces a function copy as follows:

```
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
/* copy from from[] to to[], assumes sufficient space */
    int i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Tinkering around a little with this function, I had some unexpected results.
Example program:

```
int main() {
    char a[3] = {'h', 'a', '\n'};
    char b[3];
    printf("a: %s", a); // prints ha
    copy(b, a);
    printf("a: %s", a); // prints nothing
    printf("b: %s", b); // prints ha

    return 0;
}
```

Now to my questions:

1. Why does the copying from `a` to `b` work, that is why does the while loop in copy ever terminate even though `a` does not contain a '\0'?
2. Why is `a` mutated?

Comment: It is an undefined behavior. That means that every thing is possible, absolutely everything.

Comment: Why the discrepancy between `int` and `char`? If your compiler isn't showering you with warnings, you've configured it wrong.

Comment: I assume you modified the K&R example to use `char` instead? Otherwise, all bets are off, since your code will copy chunks of 4 bytes, resulting in seg.faults and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin sorry about that, the ints were a typo. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably experiencing a buffer overflow.

As `a` is not terminated properly (missing `\0`), `copy` copies from `a` to `b` as long as it finds no `\0`. Therefore, there are more bytes written to `b` as it can contain which then overflow into `a` (platform dependent, undefined behaviour).

The part that overflows is a `\0` after `a`, thus making `a` a zero-length string.

Your stack probably looks like this:

```
                        b        a        
[ arbitrary memory ][ 0 0 0 ][ h a \n ][ 0 ? ? ? ? ]
```

The `?` indicates unknown data as we don't know what lies there and it is nowhere specified.
But we know that there *has to be* a `0`, or otherwise `printf` would print much more garbage.

`copy` copies until there is a zero found *after* the beginning `a`. There is, by chance, a
`0` after the end of `a`, which then gets copied to `b`. As `b` is already filled with the 
contents from `a`, `b` overflows into `a`, making your stack look like this:

```
                        b         a
[ arbitrary memory ][ h a \n ][ 0 a \n ][ 0 ? ? ? ? ]
```

As there's a `\0` at the beginning of `a`, `printf` assumes `a` to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

This `copy` function relies on a terminating nullbyte to determine when it should stop copying. When you use a string constant, it is automatically null-terminated. However, normal arrays are not null-terminated, so the function continues to access memory behind the end of `a` until one of the bytes there happens to be a `\0`. When the `copy` function stops copying depends on the contents of that memory area. You do not know what, if anything, happens to be there, so you have no idea how long `copy` will keep on copying or what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you did not explicitly put a `'\0'` in your variable `a`, it is very likely that `a[3]` *(which is technically **out of bounds**)* happens to be a zero.

Lots of  memory is usually filled with Zeros / `\0` values, although there is absolutely **no guarantee** of this.

That explains why you successfully copied the string to `b`.

Your copy function is wrong in the sense it "thinks" its copying arrays of `ints`:

```
void copy(int to[], int from[]) {
```

When it should be copying arrays of `char`acters:

```
void copy(char to[], int char[]) {
```

Comment: Writing `int`s over `char`s will have an effect as well...  (i.e. it will trash the stack, and is probably why `a` mutated).

Comment: Ah, I missed the int-part.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It works, because your while loop isn't doing an logical operation, its doing an asignment.
So it's as long going through the loop, as long the asigned value is true.(and thats as long it's non zero) So its terminated when the '\0' (whats 0) is reached.
and it will anywhen probably terminate (with undefined behaviour) even if there is no '\0', because after leaving your boundarys the chance of the apearance of any zero valued byte is pretty big. but after leaving your array boundaries, the behavior of your program could be anything. (it could even let nasal dragons spawn ;) )
The reason why b doesn't print anything could be grounded in the Byte order, as you are wrting int values into a Byte array, so it could be that the first Byte of the Byteorder is placed in  first Byte and is 0 so from outside it will be treat as a '\0' even if your purpose was to treat the whole int as a sign and not as 4 single values.
p.s.: This would even break strict-aliasing rules.

Answer (score 1):

Better to examine whether **to** or **from** is NULL before the while loop below.

`while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
        i++;
    }`

To your questions:

1.The loop terminates because something stored in memory after **a** equals to 0 (or '\0'), which is undefined.

2.**a** may change or not after calling **copy** which is undefined as well. Both variables stored after **a** and the position **b** stored at affect. In the case nemo mentioned above, **a** mutated after function **copy** was executed.

Always insert a '\0' at the end of a char array for security.